# Regex for extracting Data in a HTML string Multline

Tags: javascript, regex, string, axios, multiline

I'm trying to extract some data with a get request that it returns an HTML running a simple script.js in **Node**

The `data` from an `Axios.get` is an HTML i need two keys in the `<script></script>` that looks something like this:

```
more html
...
$(document).ready(function() {
        vlive.tv.common.init("en", "VE", "5454545");
        vlive.video.init("VOD", "45454", "VOD_ON_AIR", "NONE", "54454F",
            "6FABE43B271345FFCFA4D2028AF85F80C9F6",
            "V1294005a2aac29b64592ce9e636d68fb5506721c2ceac160d67a0488c1d25f3314bace9e636d68fb5506",
            [],
            "", "true", "false");
         new vlive.video.list().init("suggest", "6", "/video/suggest/more", {videoSeq:"454545", channelCode:"54545"});  new vlive.video.list().init("upcoming", "6", "/video/upcoming/more", {videoSeq:"54545", playlistSeq:"", channelCode:"5454545"}); 
        vlive.tv.live.thumb.handler.init("https://vlive-thumb.pstatic.net");
        vlive.tv.share.init("Some Title", "https://www.vlive.tv/video/xxxx", "https://v-phinf.pstatic.net/20190811_131/4509495095_JPEG/93e3a15d-bc43-11e9-a12f-5054343_43.jpg?type=a720_play", "shareVod_343434_4455457", "45454");
        vlive.video.showShoppingBanner("4544343");

    });
...
more html
```

I want this values: `"6FABE43B271345FFCFA4D2028AF85F80C9F6"` and `"V1294005a2aac29b64592ce9e636d68fb5506721c2ceac160d67a0488c1d25f3314bace9e636d68fb5506"`

With this i want to make an array like

```
{
id: '6FABE43B271345FFCFA4D2028AF85F80C9F6', 
key:'V1294005a2aac29b64592ce9e636d68fb5506721c2ceac160d67a0488c1d25f3314bace9e636d68fb5506'
}
```

I can do the array part but i really can't wrap up in my mind the RegEx part and i really tried. The most i got was using this RegEx:

```
(vlive.video.init)([\S\s]*?)\;
```

[regexr](https://regexr.com/4j6fl)

The position of the id and key is always fixed in this part as i did multiple tests with different links. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, some expression similar to,

```
(?<=")(?:[A-Z][a-f0-9]{84}|[A-F0-9]{36})(?=")
```

or,

```
[A-Z][a-f0-9]{84}|[A-F0-9]{36}
```

or,

```
"([A-Z][a-f0-9]{84}|[A-F0-9]{36})"
```

might extract those desired `id` and `key`.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/C02Hvx/1/)

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/NXx8gF/1/)

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/KOQm0l/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/KOQm0l/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

```js
const regex = /(?<=")(?:[A-Z][a-f0-9]{84}|[A-F0-9]{36})(?=")/gm;
const str = `\$(document).ready(function() {
        vlive.tv.common.init("en", "VE", "5454545");
        vlive.video.init("VOD", "45454", "VOD_ON_AIR", "NONE", "54454F",
            "6FABE43B271345FFCFA4D2028AF85F80C9F6",
            "V1294005a2aac29b64592ce9e636d68fb5506721c2ceac160d67a0488c1d25f3314bace9e636d68fb5506",
            [],
            "", "true", "false");
         new vlive.video.list().init("suggest", "6", "/video/suggest/more", {videoSeq:"454545", channelCode:"54545"});  new vlive.video.list().init("upcoming", "6", "/video/upcoming/more", {videoSeq:"54545", playlistSeq:"", channelCode:"5454545"}); 
        vlive.tv.live.thumb.handler.init("https://vlive-thumb.pstatic.net");
        vlive.tv.share.init("Some Title", "https://www.vlive.tv/video/xxxx", "https://v-phinf.pstatic.net/20190811_131/4509495095_JPEG/93e3a15d-bc43-11e9-a12f-5054343_43.jpg?type=a720_play", "shareVod_343434_4455457", "45454");
        vlive.video.showShoppingBanner("4544343");

    });`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {

if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    

    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(match);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but your regex code has some syntax Error.

Comment: I see it matches perfectly, but the problem is that it's a complete HTML string and the part i posted it was just a little part from the whole HTML string.

Comment: it works with full HTML string, thank you!